# Why does my menu with select fail the first time?

Tags: bash, menu

I tried to answer [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35114475/3220113) with a simple menu using the builtin select statement. The code displays names from `/etc/passwd`, and let you select a name by giving a number:

```
PS3="Enter a number: "
select name in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd) ; do
   if [ -n "${name}" ]; then
      break
   fi
   echo "Sorry, please enter a number as shown."
done
echo "Entry from passwd is: ${name}"
```

The works fine except for the very first time. When you give a correct answer the first time it will ask you to try again.
I tried to get a more detailed explanation of the first time, but I couldn't get a reproducable cook-book. When you copy-paste this code on your server, and give a correct answer you will probably have the same problem. When you repeat the command (from history or a new paste), the code shows now problem. I tried to get the problem again by logging out and logging in (sometimes it works) or rebooting.
I tried different ways to reproduce the problem in other situations (using different variable names, unsetting variables, using a slow list of values with `select name in $(echo One; sleep 1; echo Two; sleep 2; echo Three; sleep 1);` and opening a new shell.

I searched for other examples with `select`, but I can't find clues in other posts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16750755/3220113 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1716.

I tried to fix my code with a sync and that seems to be a work-around:

```
PS3="Enter a number: "
select name in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd) ; do
   # is sync needed here?
   sync
   if [ -n "${name}" ]; then
      break
   fi
   echo "Sorry, please enter a number as shown."
done
echo "Entry from passwd is: ${name}"
```

I couldn't reproduce the error when I include the sync command. Is sync really a working patch and why do I need this here?

I do not need other ways to write a menu. I already found the graphical dialog [Dialog from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8354482/3220113) and was looking for a simple replacement of my own over-complicated https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115371/57293.

Comment: `sync` is for flushing buffers to files, it has nothing to do with shell variables.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. It works the first time for me. http://ideone.com/ogpver

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce it by pasting the commands into the interactive shell, instead of running them in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem only occurs when you type the commands interactively, not in a script. The reason is that the line you type after the `select` line is being used as the response to the prompt. Since `if` isn't in the menu, it reports an error. Then it doesn't execute the `if` command, because it was read as the response to the prompt.

It's not a problem in a script because the commands in the script are not used as standard input.

Comment: Pasting is the magic word. And not pasting `select name in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd) ; do 2 ;   if [ -n "${name}" ]; then       break;    fi;        echo "Sorry, please enter a number as shown."; done; echo "Entry from passwd is: ${name}"` but something with newlines. The `2` is an attempt to paste 2 as an answer, but first select reads input and than bash reports that 2 is not a command.