# Ksh - Script: List Files and store as variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm using `ksh`on an `HP-UX` box.

In a portion of my script, I want to list certain files (`*.xml`), have them numbered and have the user choose a file by typing the number and hitting enter. That filename will then be stored as a variable.

Example of output:

```
Please choose a file:   
1) bar27.xml      
2) foo1.xml    
3) foobar4.xml
```

Then the user types in `1`, `2`, or `3` and hit enter.  The file name chosen needs to be stored as a variable. So if the user chooses `2` the variable should contain `foo1.xml`.

Comment: You need to look up the `select` built-in.  It's designed to support that.  Note that a web-based search may be trickier; `select` has lots of meanings.  Searching with 'ksh select' gets on -topic results for me, including [Linux script `select` menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750160/linux-script-select-menu).

Comment: If you still have trouble after that, update your Q with your best attempt to use `select` and leave a comment that you have updated your Q. If you get it working either post your Answer (you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points) or delete this Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with the following which works:

```
files=$(ls *.xml)
i=1

for j in $files
do
echo "$i) $j"
file[i]=$j
i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

echo "Choose an XML file from above to use:"
read v_CHOOSELIST
echo "File chosen: ${file[$v_CHOOSELIST]}"
```

Comment: Good shot. Even better: Try someting with select (search on http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+menu+bash ) and update the question when your stuck.

Comment: some comments: your script will not work as expected if a filename contains whitespace. [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and use a real array `files=( *.xml )`. Then `for i in "${!files[@]}"; do echo "$i) ${files[i]}"; done`

Comment: but select is way easier: `PS3="Choose an XML file from above to use:"; select file in *.xml; do if [ -n "$file" ]; then break; fi; done; echo "you chose $file"`